# Why can't I use distance method from java.awt.geom.Point2D?

Tags: java

I can't use `distance()` from Point2D. Please help me fix my code, thank you!

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double;

public class TestPoint2D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter point 1");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Enter point 2");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();
        
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(x1, y1);
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(x2, y2);
        System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_I can't use distance()_". What happens when you try to?

Comment: It said, "The method distance(Point2D) is undefined for the type Point2D."

Comment: [`Point2D JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) states: _This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D coordinate_. You should use the implementation of [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).

Comment: So, you mean that public double distance(Point2D pt) is an abstract method even if it doesn't contain "abstract" keyword in its signature? Sorry for stupid question, I'm a newbie

Comment: `Point2D` is an abstract class. Therefore you can not instantiate it. You need to use the implementation of this abstract class, `Point`, which you can instantiate. After that, you can use `distance(...)` as you tried before. Because this method is defined in `Point2D` and `Point` is a subclass, therefore inheriting it. For further reading: [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Point2D docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) say:

> This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D coordinate. The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to the subclass.

So you need to use [Point2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) or [Point2D.Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Float.html) to initialize the object.

So this code to initialize `Point2D` works:

```java
Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double(x1, y1);
Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double(x2, y2);
```

This "problem" is because `Point2D` is an abtract class. You can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp) how works if you have doubts. But, to associate it with the "Point2D problem", check the first paragraphs and you will understand better.

> **Abstract class**: is a restricted class that cannot be used to create objects (to access it, it must be inherited from another class).

That's exactly the problem (cannot create objects) and the solution (inherit from another class)